# Empty message content when sending Clickatell SMS via Marketo third-party service

Tags: rest, webhooks, marketo, clickatell, httpapi

I'm having issues with Clickatell sending SMS via Marketo webhook.

There is no error coming from Marketo so I'm not sure where the issue is. I'm using iPhone with Three UK coverage, where I receive an empty message; and I've also tested Android and another iPhone on O2 network, which are not receiving any at all.

If anyone could help with this, I'd be forever grateful!

Thanks,
Livia

This is the JSON Payload template used:

{ "content": "Hello there", "to": [ "{{lead.Phone Number}}" ], "binary": true, "clientMessageId": "University of London", "charset": "UTF-8" }

- I'm adding the headers with the Authorization API ID and content-type - application/json.

API response after running it through smart campaign in marketo to a UK number:

Pay Load:
{ "content": "Hello there", "to": [ "447402516XXX" ], "binary": true, "clientMessageId": "University of London", "charset": "UTF-8" }

Response:
{"responseCode":202,"messages":[{"apiMessageId":"6e961bdcdefb4d62b543c123df502aff","accepted":true,"to":"4474025167XX","errorCode":null,"error":null,"errorDescription":null}]}

PS I ve tried both in Sandbox and Production environments in Clickatell setup.

Comment: This has now been solved - the issue was the binary field needed to be set to 'false'